# Google Maps Heatmap in JavaFX WebEngine errors

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have created a HTML/JS page that displays a google map with a HeatMap.

This page works perfectly within a browser however when run within a Javafx WebEngine, the map displays perfectly but the heat map only appears for an instance when zooming on quickly moving the map.

```
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        final String urlGoogleMaps = "https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/layer-heatmap";
        webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps);
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Is there something i'm missing? Or is this a limitation of Javafx WebEngine?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I similarly have issues with google map pins. They are only an issue in JavaFX and not the browser.

Zooming for me helped too. In my javascript I change the zoom after each update:

```
var zoom = map.getZoom();
map.setZoom(zoom+1);
map.setZoom(zoom);
```

Every time you need the webview to reload the map, I change the zoom. Currently I have a slight flicker, but until this bug is fixed I am okay with it since I only have an issue each time I update which isn't so often.

Comment: Thanks man,
From what I learnt, it seems to be a Mac problem. Defaultly it uses an older WebKit to render the WebEngine. Therefore it'll load fine on other browsers or other operating systems.
Just waiting for a JavaFX update at this point.